# How to display the last result in a FOR list

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following list:

```
{% for artist_form in artist_formset %} 
...
{% endfor %}
```

How can I display just the last result in the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In views.py:

```
last_artist = artist_formset[-1]
```

In your-template.html:

```
{{ last_artist }}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#last

Use 'last' tag to get the last item of a list.